# PHP and My SQL Search

Tags: php

I have little experience with PHP so this question might seem a little naive compared to what you do here with that language 
but anyway I have a database which consists of id, word, meaning:
this code works just fine to search for one word but I have trouble searching for two or more words. if i type in two words it says no results can anybody help me out and tell me what's wrong (THANKS)

```
<div class="https">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input id="http" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
    </form>
</div>
<?php 
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("new_database") or die("could not find database");
        $output = '';

        if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {
            $searchq = $_POST['search'];
            $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);

           $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database_mysql WHERE word  LIKE '%$searchq%' 
            OR meaning LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("coudn't search");


           $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

           if($count==0)
           {
               $output = 'no results';
           } else {
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
               {
                   $id = $row['id'];
                   $word = $row['word'];
                   $meaning = $row['meaning'];

                   print "<div><h4>$word</h4>
                   $meaning <br /> <br /></div>";
               }
           }
        }
        print "<h4>$output</h4>";
     ?>
```

Comment: basically: ..`WHERE word  LIKE '%$search1% OR  word  LIKE '%$search2%`... hope that gets you started

Comment: Have you added a second input box, or did you mean if you type two or more words into the same input box?

Comment: @Dagon that doesn't help because search is a variable cannot change it;

Comment: sure you can, if they type 2 words, you split them on the space

Comment: @Don't Panic i mean if I search for a person say Peter Pan; if i search only for Peter or Pan (if it's in the database) it's gonna give me a result but if i search for Peter Pan it's not; that's the problem have no idea how to fix it i've tried several techniques but still not working

Comment: can you please show the way you'd do that

Comment: i see @Vertig0 has done that for you below

Answer (score 1):

By your code i assume that you want to type 2 words and get the meaning of that 2 words if its are in the database.

But that won't work because the final query will be like

```
SELECT * FROM database_mysql WHERE word  LIKE '%WORD1 WORD2%' 
        OR meaning LIKE '%$WORD1 WORD2%'"
```

And there is no register that match that filter.

I think you are only experimenting, so for put this to work you can explode the search by space

```
$words = explode(" ", $_POST["search"]);
```

(you need to modify your regex pattern to allow spaces)

$words will be an array containing any word, then you could query the DB for any word or make it in one query adding "LIKES" to the query with a loop.

Something like:

```
$words = explode(" ", $searchq);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM database_mysql ";
    $first = true;

    foreach ($words as $word) 
    {
        $connector = ($first) ? " WHERE " : " OR ";

        $query     .= " $connector (word LIKE '%$word%' OR meaning LIKE '%$word%')";

        $first     = false;
    }

...
```

Important to say that this is ok to experiment, but not for a real search, the query could take a lot of time and resources, you must use mysqli or PDO, etc...

Comment: I have tried different ways but it isn't working as i want; could you  please  write the whole code for me i'd be much obliged

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have unbalanced parenthesis here:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
```

Which looks like it would cause errors. But to fix your issue, you could try running multiple queries and combining the result with something like

```
array_merge( $query_1, $query_2);
```